# Is there a name for speaking to the person you're talking to as if you're speaking to somebody else

Tags: single-word-requests

For example if you were on an airplane and somebody was kicking the back of your seat, you might say to your companion "Please stop kicking my seat", when what you actually mean is "It's annoying that the person behind me is kicking the back of my seat"

Comment: Passive-aggressive.

Comment: Are you really asking about this, or are you asking about saying *to your companion* "I do wish the person behind me would stop kicking my seat" (loud enough for them to overhear) when you might usefully tell that person directly? I can't imagine asking my companion to stop kicking my seat when they're not.

Comment: I think OP is asking about saying it as a kind of prayer addressed to nobody in particular, but loud enough that their companion can hear and knows of OP's plight.

Comment: See [this scene](http://www.wat.tv/video/femme-boulanger-g4kh_2fgqp_.html) from *La Femme du Boulanger*, between 3min04sec to 6min04sec, for a fabulous example of this (in French). The baker scolds the cat for straying, in front of his wife who is the real, indirect target.

Comment: *Allusion* comes close. I would say to my seat-mate: "There seems to be some major turbulence around my seat."

Comment: @Gerger I think you're right, that's really my question: When you say something which isn't addressed to the person you say it to.

Comment: @aswan then I can't think of a single way to describe that action without using a phrase like, "so only my companion could hear."

Comment: I would call it "covert criticism" or "complaining by indirection." Your companion is a convenient foil that enables you to voice your annoyance without directly confronting the actual (and known) culprit. As Gerger suggests, this tactic's extreme lack of straightforwardness causes it to border on passive-aggressive behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tact.

You are giving the offending person an opportunity to save face.